# Defining limits of box around a barplot in R

Tags: r, plot, axis, box

I have created a barplot with 24 bars on the x-axis (0-23) and background shading using the following code:

```
#Data
Hours = seq(from=0, to=23)
Mean = rnorm(24, mean=5, sd=2)

#Create number seq for tick mark locations
at_tick = seq_len(length(Hours)+1) 

#Plot with background rectangle shading
x=barplot(Mean,names.arg=Hours, border="white", ylab="Freq", xlab="Hour", 
          ylim=c(0,10), axes=FALSE, space=0, col="grey50")
X = c(0,5)
Y = c(0,10)
rect(X[1], Y[1], X[2], Y[2], border = "gray80", col = "gray80")
X2 = c(19,24)
Y2 = c(0,10)
rect(X2[1], Y2[1], X2[2], Y2[2], border = "gray80", col = "gray80")
barplot(Mean,names.arg=Hours, ylim=c(0,10), border="white", ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE, space=0, col="gray50", add=TRUE) 
axis(2, las=2, pos=0)
axis(1, at = at_tick -1, pos=0, labels = FALSE)

box(which="plot", bty="]") #add a box around the plot
```

This creates a plot with a surrounding box that extends beyond the limits of the x-axis in both directions. Instead, I would like to add a box around the plot that aligns with the axis limits (i.e. x-axis: 0-23, y-axis: 0-10). I have spent ages trying to find a way to do this with no luck. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What about `xlim=c(0,23)` in the first call to `barplot`?

Comment: Thanks, but this prevents a final tick mark being drawn for bar 23, and doesn't solve the box issue on the left-hand side of the x-axis i.e. box margins extending below x=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about drawing individual lines?  You can use the `segment` function instead of `box` to do this:

```
segments(24,10, 24,0)
segments(0,10, 24,10)
```

Complete code:

```
#Data
Hours = seq(from=0, to=23)
Mean = rnorm(24, mean=5, sd=2)

#Create number seq for tick mark locations
at_tick = seq_len(length(Hours)+1) 

#Plot with background rectangle shading
x=barplot(Mean,names.arg=Hours, border="white", ylab="Freq", xlab="Hour", 
          ylim=c(0,10), axes=FALSE, space=0, col="grey50")
X = c(0,5)
Y = c(0,10)
rect(X[1], Y[1], X[2], Y[2], border = "gray80", col = "gray80")
X2 = c(19,24)
Y2 = c(0,10)
rect(X2[1], Y2[1], X2[2], Y2[2], border = "gray80", col = "gray80")
barplot(Mean,names.arg=Hours, ylim=c(0,10), border="white", ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE, space=0, col="gray50", add=TRUE) 
axis(2, las=2, pos=0)
axis(1, at = at_tick -1, pos=0, labels = FALSE)

segments(24,10, 24,0)
segments(0,10, 24,10)
```

[image]

Comment: @ ajb. thanks. Segments works for the top border, but not the right of some reason? Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm works for me, I've edited my answer to include the exact code and image I get when I run it.  is this what you're looking for?  do you see the same plot when you run that code?

Comment: Thanks. On further inspection the problem seems to be related to using segments() in a quartz() window. It works fine when using the default graphics window in RStudio. Not sure why that would be, but your solution is a great one. Thanks!